# How to edit and save Python file via command-line

Tags: linux, python-3.x, docker, conan

I have a Dockerfile that in one of its RUN instructions creates a conan file. I'd like to edit and save that conan file in my Dockerfile to set project specific settings. Is there a way to do so  via command line, for example the Python prompt?

Alternatively is there a way to embed a Python file in a Dockerfile?

Comment: What do you mean by `do so via command line`? And use `ADD` to add a python file to image is not what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any command to do so. But I would suggest you to use another approach :

1. Create a Conan template file with **environment variables** as **placeholders** (`youconanfile.dist`).
2. use `envsubst` command in order to runtime-create the file you need with current project variables.

I use this technique [in a Docker stack](https://github.com/compagnie-hyperactive/docker-boilerplate-wordpress/blob/master/Makefile#L42) to generate multiple files (`wp-cli.yml`, `deploy.php`...). My example is in a `Makefile`. If you need to use it in your `Dockerfile`, it is possible assuming that

- `envsubst` is installed on your container
- `COPY` command is used for pushing the Conan template file in your container.